# General expression for this reccurent derivative?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I stumbled upon a problem that can be distilled to:

Let $\Delta_m(x)$ be some function that depends on $x$ such that

$$ \delta_{x}\Delta_m(x) = \Delta_{m+1}(x)$$

where $\delta_{x} $ is the derivative with respect to $x$. I'm interested in solving exactly

$$(x\delta_{x})^m[\Delta_0(x)]$$

where $(x\delta_{x})^m$ denotes $m$ applications of the operator $(x\delta_{x})$ onto $\Delta_0(x)$.

Doing a few applications by hand yields (I omit the $x$ dependency for clarity)

$$ x\Delta_1$$
$$ x\Delta_1+x^2\Delta_2$$
$$ x\Delta_1+x^2\Delta_2+2x^2\Delta_2 +x^3\Delta_3$$
etc...

Arranging coefficients in a triangle by powers of $x^n \Delta_n$ yields a "Pascal-triangle-like" diagram

$$ 1 $$
$$ 1\ 1\ $$
$$ 1\ 3\ 1\ $$
$$ 1\ 7\ 6\ 1$$
$$ 1\ 9\ 25\ 10\ 1$$
$$ ... $$

for which I cannot seem to find the combinatorial expression. What would be the general expression for the $m^{th}$ row?

Comment: Up until your final row, these were Sterling Numbers of the Second Kind:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: Thank @SammyBlack, this pointed me to a mistake! The final row should indeed read 1 15 25 10 1. And Sterling Numbers are what I was looking for.